# Looping posts in devise signup/signin view (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

I want to loop all the posts all users have created within the devise signup and sign in views. Not sure where to paste @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc") at.

Comment: BTW, your query should be `@posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc)` (without the all)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the controllers Devise uses by running:

```
rails generate devise:controllers
```

This will make all its controllers readily available for editing.  Then in your sessions/new action (sign in page ) you can add that @posts line.  And Registrations/new would be your sign up page.  It's in the Devise Documentation under "Configuring Devise Controllers".